# D3.js Bar graph not displaying properly?

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar graph in my program, but it doesn't seem to be displaying properly. All of the bars seem to be a lot bigger than they are supposed to be. Here's the relevant code:

```
//Bar Graph

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var values = [1, 2, 3]

var colours = ['#FA0', '#0AF', '#AF0']

var data = []

var yOffset = 0

//create scale
yRange2 = d3.scale.linear().range([canvas.height - MARGINS.top,
MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0, 6]);

//Process the data

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var datum = {

        value: yRange2(values[i]),
        colour: colours[i],
        x: 0,
        y: yOffset

    }

    yOffset += datum.value;

    data.push(datum)

}

//setup y
yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange2)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSubdivide(true);

canvas.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis2);

var bars = canvas.selectAll('rect').data(data)

bars
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        width: 30,
        x: 60,
        y: function (d) {
            return d.y
        },
        height: function (d) {
            return d.value;
        }

    })
    .style({
        fill: function (d) {
            return d.colour
        }
    })

//updates when slider changes
$("#myRange").change(function () {
    slider = $("#myRange").val();

    updateXs();
    updateLineData();
    displayVals();

    d3.select(".myLine").transition()
        .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData));
});
```

And here's the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tqj5maza/7/

To me, it looks like the bars are starting at the top for some reason, and then going downwards, hence the cutoff. The height for each seems too large, though.

Comment: Your bar chart doesn't have xaxis for the bar chart. That is the reason why they are coming one top of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting the `rects` height property correctly.  [Generally](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/) this is height of the plotting area minus y position.  The way you have your code structured its:

```
height: function (d) {
    return canvas.height - MARGINS.top - d.value;
}
```

To fix the overlapping x value, you should set up an x `d3.scale` but a quick and dirty way would be:

```
x: function(d,i){
    return (i + 1) * 60; //<-- move each bar over 60 pixels
}
```

Updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tqj5maza/9/).

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, but the reason that I had put the X values as the same is because I'm trying to get my bars to stack into a single column. How would I go about doing that then?

Comment: @gamehen, oh, now I understand.  You were close with your `yOffset` variable, but what you needed has a running total of the height, not the y position.  Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqj5maza/10/)